# Difficulty setting up dynamic UI with nested reactivity in shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, nested, shiny-reactivity

**First thing first, here is a runnable example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)

###################################################################################

MTX_UI <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(6, titlePanel("Calculator"))),
    fluidRow(numericInput("Ninf", "Ninf", 1,
                          min = 1, max = 12, step = 1) %>% column(., width = 3)),
    tags$div(id = "InfPanel"),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3, actionButton("calculate", "Calculate")))
)

###################################################################################

MTX_Server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #UI creation
    change_Ninf <- reactive({input[["Ninf"]]})
    ExistNinf <<- 0

  #Creating inf panels
    observeEvent(change_Ninf(), {
      Ninf <- change_Ninf()
      if (Ninf>ExistNinf) {    
        #Decide list to insert
          if (ExistNinf==0) {lstToIns <- seq(Ninf)} else {lstToIns <- seq(Ninf)[-seq(ExistNinf)]}
        #Update list inserted
          ExistNinf <<- Ninf
        #Insert UI & reactive component
          for (InfN in lstToIns) {
            #Insert UI
              insertUI(
                selector = '#InfPanel',
                ui = conditionalPanel(paste0("input.Ninf >= ", InfN),
                                      hr(),
                                      wellPanel(
                                        fluidRow(column(3, titlePanel(paste0("Inf #", InfN)))),
                                        fluidRow(column(3, numericInput(paste0("Nobs_", InfN),
                                                                        "Nobs:", 2, min = 2, max = 12, step = 1)),
                                                 column(3, textInput(paste0("Var10_", InfN), "Var10:", 12)),
                                                 column(3, textInput(paste0("Var11_", InfN), "Var11:", 1.3)),
                                                 column(3, textInput(paste0("Var12_", InfN), "Var12:", 6))
                                        ),
                                        fluidRow(column(2, "VAR1:"),
                                                 column(2, "VAR2:"),
                                                 column(1, "VAR3:"),
                                                 column(1, "VAR4:"),
                                                 column(2, "VAR5:"),
                                                 column(1, "VAR6:"),
                                                 column(1, "VAR7:")
                                        ),
                                        fluidRow(
                                          column(1, offset = 4, checkboxInput(paste0("fix_VAR3_", InfN), "Same", FALSE)),
                                          column(1, checkboxInput(paste0("fix_VAR4_", InfN), "Same", FALSE)),
                                          column(2, checkboxInput(paste0("fix_VAR5_", InfN), "Same", FALSE)),
                                          column(1, checkboxInput(paste0("fix_VAR6_", InfN), "Same", FALSE)),
                                          column(1, checkboxInput(paste0("fix_VAR7_", InfN), "Same", FALSE))
                                        ),
                                        tags$div(id = paste0("ObsPanel_", InfN))
                                      ))
              )
            #Create fixation reactive components
              assign(paste0("react_fix_VAR3_", InfN), reactive({input[[paste0("fix_VAR3_", InfN)]]}), inherits = T)
              assign(paste0("react_fix_VAR4_", InfN), reactive({input[[paste0("fix_VAR4_", InfN)]]}), inherits = T)
              assign(paste0("react_fix_VAR5_", InfN), reactive({input[[paste0("fix_VAR5_", InfN)]]}), inherits = T)
              assign(paste0("react_fix_VAR6_", InfN), reactive({input[[paste0("fix_VAR6_", InfN)]]}), inherits = T)
              assign(paste0("react_fix_VAR7_", InfN), reactive({input[[paste0("fix_VAR7_", InfN)]]}), inherits = T)
            #Update Obs reactive components
              assign(paste0("change_Nobs_", InfN), reactive({input[[paste0("Nobs_", InfN)]]}), inherits = T)
            #Creating Obs components
              if (!exists(paste0("ExistNobs_", InfN))) {assign(paste0("ExistNobs_", InfN), 0)}
              observeEvent(get(paste0("change_Nobs_", InfN))(), {
                Nobs <- get(paste0("change_Nobs_", InfN))()
                ExistNobs <- get(paste0("ExistNobs_", InfN))
                if (Nobs>ExistNobs) {
                  #Decide list to insert
                    if (ExistNobs==0) {lstToIns_obs <- seq(Nobs)} else {lstToIns_obs <- seq(Nobs)[-seq(ExistNobs)]}
                  #Update list inserted
                    assign(paste0("ExistNobs_", InfN), Nobs, inherits = T)
                  #Insert UI
                    for (ObsN in lstToIns_obs) {
                      if (ObsN==1) {
                        insertUI(
                          selector = paste0("#ObsPanel_", InfN),
                          ui = conditionalPanel(paste0("input.Nobs_", InfN, " >= ", 1),
                                                fluidRow(
                                                  column(2, textInput(paste0("VAR1_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 0)),
                                                  column(2, textInput(paste0("VAR2_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 0)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR3_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR4_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(2, textInput(paste0("VAR5_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR6_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR7_", InfN, "_", 1), NULL, 1))
                                                ))
                        )
                        shinyjs::useShinyjs()
                        shinyjs::disable(paste0("VAR1_", InfN, "_1"))
                        shinyjs::disable(paste0("VAR2_", InfN, "_1"))
                      } else {
                        insertUI(
                          selector = paste0("#ObsPanel_", InfN),
                          ui = conditionalPanel(paste0("input.Nobs_", InfN, " >= ", ObsN),
                                                fluidRow(
                                                  column(2, textInput(paste0("VAR1_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(2, textInput(paste0("VAR2_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR3_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR4_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(2, textInput(paste0("VAR5_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR6_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1)),
                                                  column(1, textInput(paste0("VAR7_", InfN, "_", ObsN), NULL, 1))
                                                ))
                        )
                        local({
                          observeEvent(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR3_", InfN))(), {
                            shinyjs::toggleState(paste0("VAR3_", InfN, "_", ObsN), !(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR3_", InfN))()))
                          })
                          observeEvent(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR4_", InfN))(), {
                            shinyjs::toggleState(paste0("VAR4_", InfN, "_", ObsN), !(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR4_", InfN))()))
                          })
                          observeEvent(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR5_", InfN))(), {
                            shinyjs::toggleState(paste0("VAR5_", InfN, "_", ObsN), !(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR5_", InfN))()))
                          })
                          observeEvent(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR6_", InfN))(), {
                            shinyjs::toggleState(paste0("VAR6_", InfN, "_", ObsN), !(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR6_", InfN))()))
                          })
                          observeEvent(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR7_", InfN))(), {
                            shinyjs::toggleState(paste0("VAR7_", InfN, "_", ObsN), !(get(paste0("react_fix_VAR7_", InfN))()))
                          })
                        })
                      }
                    }
                }
              })
          }
      }
    })
}

###################################################################################

shinyApp(MTX_UI, MTX_Server)
```

I expect the followings:

> 1. When the user changes `Ninf` (at the top of the App), the number of Inf `wellPanel` shown changes accordingly. (top-layer reactive)
> 2. For each Inf `wellPanel`, when the user changes `Nobs`, the number of observation rows to input will change accordingly. (2nd-layer reactive)
> 3. When each Inf `wellPanel` is generated, the first `textInput` boxes under each of `VAR1` and `VAR2` should be disabled automatically (by `shinyjs::disable`).
> 4. For each Inf `wellPanel`, when the `Same` box under each of `VAR3` to `VAR7` is checked, all `textInput` boxes below that `VARx` (EXCEPT for the first one) should be disabled (by `shinyjs::toggleState`). (3rd-layer reactive)

So far, I am successful for #1 and #2. But my effort to achieve #3 and #4 is in vain so far and there has been much struggling...

I started off hard-coding everything (with `max.Ninf=12` and `max.Nobs=12`) but it turned out that the load time was long since it has to load all objects at once - in fact, usually the users will only use the first two Inf panels. So I turned to this nested-structure approach and tried to use `insertUI`. But then the above problem is stopping me from moving forward.

Thanks!